# How to get Core data sqlite file location

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to find the sqlite file location created by core data. I am using the below code:

```
print("Documents Directory: ", FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last ?? "Not Found!")
```

And it's showing me the result: ile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/148690BC-21F4-4239-99B2-5F947023B414/Library/Application Support

But I can't find any sqlite file in the location.

Can any one please help me to solve the issue. I am using Swift 4 and testing my code in iPhone 6sPlus

Answer (score 1):

Unless your app is document-based, the default location for your app's sqlite database is its *Application Support* directory, not *Documents*.  Change `.documentDirectory` to `.applicationSupportDirectory`.